# How does a window function get applied to complex number data?

Tags: math, signal-processing

Does the real and/or imaginary part get multiplied by the same coefficient or does the window frame size have to be doubled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real and imaginary parts get multiplied by the same coefficient.  It's pretty clear if you consider the equation:

```
windowed[n] = win[n] * x[n]
```

where `win` is the window function (all real) and `x` is the signal to be windowed (could be strictly real or complex).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you normally want a linear operation dot product when you window before, say, a complex FFT:

```
W dot C === (W dot R) + i(W dot I)
```